# How to share gradle dependencies between Android application and its library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play

In my Android application I have google play billing implementation, I have it defined in build.gradle as:

> implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'

Also, I have my self created library for some shared code to integrated into my project. In that library I want to implement google play billing implementation code. For that as well I have define the billing library in build.gradle file of library.

I am using gradle version :

> 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'

Is there any option to define the library only one place (build.gradle) and use it from both the places?

Comment: You can use api instead of implementation in you library: `api 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'` and the this dependency will be available in your project after connecting the library. If your library located into your project as separate module you can use ext variables on application level for add dependencies.

Comment: Marking it as 'api' works great! Thanks @p.alexey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Gradle Plugin version 3.0.0, there is a nicer way to do this. We can control whether each dependency is available for only the current module, or for the current module AND any modules which depend on it. This will allow us to easily share dependencies across modules within a project.

Here's how we used to declare dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'
```

Here are the new configurations which should replace compile:

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'
```

this dependency is only used within this modAPI

```
api 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'
```

this dependency will also be available in any builds that depend on this module. Assuming that we have a module named 'library' that is consumed by the 'app' module, we can use the api configuration to declare that the dependency should be shared with any module that depends on it.

library module `build.gradle`

```
  dependencies {

        // dependencies marked 'implementation' will only be available to the current module    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'


        // any dependencies marked 'api' will also be available to app module

api 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2' 

    }
    app module build.gradle:

    dependencies {

        // declare dependency on library module
        implementation project(':library')

        // only need to declare dependencies unique to app 
        implementation 'example.dependency:1.0.0'
    }
```

Please see this for further information and diagrams.
https://medium.com/@julesrosser/handling-gradle-dependencies-in-multiple-module-android-projects-9e590c3d20dc

Comment: Is there not a way to prevent having ```api 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'```  littered everywhere?